# Delayed callback function on slide event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, timeout, delay, jquery-ui-slider

I am making use of jqueryui's slider widget.
I wish to run a function on the slider's slide event, but I only want it to run after a (700ms) delay. If the slider handle keeps moving (i.e. triggering slide again), then I want the delay timeout to reset.

I have attempted to use jquery's doTimeout as well as setTimeout to no avail. Anything I do appears to keep the slider handle from changing position.

```
var heavy = {
    updatesomething: function() {
        //some computationally heavy code
    }
}

$('#slider').slider({
    min:1, max:99, orientation: 'vertical',
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).doTimeout('timeoutid', 700, function() {
            heavy.updatesomething(this, ui.value);  });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a debounce implementation available out there. Below example is taken from [davidwalsh blog](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function). Also instead of passing around the context, you use `apply` as shown below to invoke the function with right context and arguments.

```js
var heavy = {
  updatesomething: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(ui);
  }
}

// taken from https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

$('#slider').slider({
  min: 1,
  max: 99,
  orientation: 'vertical',
  slide: debounce(function(event, ui) {
    heavy.updatesomething.apply(this, arguments);
    //---------------------------^-context  ^-- what it says
  }, 700)
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with debounce in this case, is that if the user keeps moving the slider there will be no events. So it's more useful to use throttling.

The example below also includes the full lodash Throttle and Debounce

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Creates a debounced function that delays invoking `func` until after `wait`
 * milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was
 * invoked. The debounced function comes with a `cancel` method to cancel
 * delayed `func` invocations and a `flush` method to immediately invoke them.
 * Provide `options` to indicate whether `func` should be invoked on the
 * leading and/or trailing edge of the `wait` timeout. The `func` is invoked
 * with the last arguments provided to the debounced function. Subsequent
 * calls to the debounced function return the result of the last `func`
 * invocation.
 *
 * **Note:** If `leading` and `trailing` options are `true`, `func` is
 * invoked on the trailing edge of the timeout only if the debounced function
 * is invoked more than once during the `wait` timeout.
 *
 * If `wait` is `0` and `leading` is `false`, `func` invocation is deferred
 * until to the next tick, similar to `setTimeout` with a timeout of `0`.
 *
 * See [David Corbacho's article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)
 * for details over the differences between `_.debounce` and `_.throttle`.
 *
 * from lodash - https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.16.2/lodash.js#L10218
 */
function debounce(func, wait, options) {
 if (!options) options = {};

 let lastArgs, lastThis, maxWait, result, timerId, lastCallTime, lastInvokeTime = 0,
  leading = false,
  maxing = false,
  trailing = true;

 wait = wait || 0;
 leading = !!options.leading;
 maxing = 'maxWait' in options;
 maxWait = maxing ? Math.max(options.maxWait || 0, wait) : maxWait;
 trailing = 'trailing' in options ? !!options.trailing : trailing;

 function invokeFunc(time) {
  const args = lastArgs,
   thisArg = lastThis;

  lastArgs = lastThis = undefined;
  lastInvokeTime = time;
  result = func.apply(thisArg, args);
  return result;
 }

 function leadingEdge(time) {
  // Reset any `maxWait` timer.
  lastInvokeTime = time;
  // Start the timer for the trailing edge.
  timerId = setTimeout(timerExpired, wait);
  // Invoke the leading edge.
  return leading ? invokeFunc(time) : result;
 }

 function remainingWait(time) {
  const timeSinceLastCall = time - lastCallTime,
   timeSinceLastInvoke = time - lastInvokeTime,
   result = wait - timeSinceLastCall;

  return maxing ? Math.min(result, maxWait - timeSinceLastInvoke) : result;
 }

 function shouldInvoke(time) {
  const timeSinceLastCall = time - lastCallTime,
   timeSinceLastInvoke = time - lastInvokeTime;

  // Either this is the first call, activity has stopped and we're at the
  // trailing edge, the system time has gone backwards and we're treating
  // it as the trailing edge, or we've hit the `maxWait` limit.
  return (lastCallTime === undefined || (timeSinceLastCall >= wait) ||
   (timeSinceLastCall < 0) || (maxing && timeSinceLastInvoke >= maxWait));
 }

 function timerExpired() {
  const time = Date.now();
  if (shouldInvoke(time)) {
   return trailingEdge(time);
  }
  // Restart the timer.
  timerId = setTimeout(timerExpired, remainingWait(time));
 }

 function trailingEdge(time) {
  timerId = undefined;

  // Only invoke if we have `lastArgs` which means `func` has been
  // debounced at least once.
  if (trailing && lastArgs) {
   return invokeFunc(time);
  }
  lastArgs = lastThis = undefined;
  return result;
 }

 function cancel() {
  if (timerId !== undefined) {
   clearTimeout(timerId);
  }
  lastInvokeTime = 0;
  lastArgs = lastCallTime = lastThis = timerId = undefined;
 }

 function flush() {
  return timerId === undefined ? result : trailingEdge(Date.now());
 }

 function debounced(...args) {
  const time = Date.now(),
   isInvoking = shouldInvoke(time);

  lastArgs = args;
  lastThis = this;
  lastCallTime = time;

  if (isInvoking) {
   if (timerId === undefined) {
    return leadingEdge(lastCallTime);
   }
   if (maxing) {
    // Handle invocations in a tight loop.
    timerId = setTimeout(timerExpired, wait);
    return invokeFunc(lastCallTime);
   }
  }
  if (timerId === undefined) {
   timerId = setTimeout(timerExpired, wait);
  }
  return result;
 }
 debounced.cancel = cancel;
 debounced.flush = flush;
 return debounced;
}

/**
 * Creates a throttled function that only invokes `func` at most once per
 * every `wait` milliseconds. The throttled function comes with a `cancel`
 * method to cancel delayed `func` invocations and a `flush` method to
 * immediately invoke them. Provide `options` to indicate whether `func`
 * should be invoked on the leading and/or trailing edge of the `wait`
 * timeout. The `func` is invoked with the last arguments provided to the
 * throttled function. Subsequent calls to the throttled function return the
 * result of the last `func` invocation.
 *
 * **Note:** If `leading` and `trailing` options are `true`, `func` is
 * invoked on the trailing edge of the timeout only if the throttled function
 * is invoked more than once during the `wait` timeout.
 *
 * If `wait` is `0` and `leading` is `false`, `func` invocation is deferred
 * until to the next tick, similar to `setTimeout` with a timeout of `0`.
 *
 * See [David Corbacho's article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)
 * for details over the differences between `_.throttle` and `_.debounce`.
 */
function throttle(func, wait, options) {
 if (!options) options = {};
 let leading = true,
  trailing = true;

 leading = 'leading' in options ? !!options.leading : leading;
 trailing = 'trailing' in options ? !!options.trailing : trailing;

 return debounce(func, wait, {
  'leading': leading,
  'maxWait': wait,
  'trailing': trailing
 });
}


let counter=0;

$('#slider').slider({
  min: 1,
  max: 99,
  orientation: 'vertical',
  slide: throttle(function(event, ui) {
    $(event.target).slider('option', 'value', ui.value); // making sure value is correct
    console.log(ui.value);
  }, 100)
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```